# Corn Starch vs Potato Starch

Tags: ingredient-selection, cornstarch, starch

One of the recipes I am trying out asks me to use Potato starch to help thicken the sauce. A majority of the recipes I found online for it say to use Potato starch but at the store I mainly found corn starch.

I was wondering if there are any really big differences other than the obvious one that I should be aware of when substituting between these two starches. Are they interchangeable or is there a big difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are interchangeable 1:1, with virtually no changes needed. There shouldn't be any difference in the final sauce except that the cornstarch thickened one will be a bit more opaque. If you substitute the other way (use potato starch instead of cornstarch) don't let it hard boil (not for safety reasons, just aesthetics). In what country was the recipe developed? Could the need for potato starch instead of corn starch in your recipe have to do with Passover rules?

Comment: The recipe is for Ma Po Doufu, so its an authentic Chinese recipe. Not entirely sure if it applies XD

Comment: Well it probably has nothing to do with Passover, but the culinary rules should apply nicely :).

Comment: Have you tried the 1:1 substitute? The potato starch I have says to use 1 1/2 TB for every 1 TB of cornstarch when substituting.

Comment: @user61524 I have used both starches 1:1. If your potato starch says otherwise, remember it's way easier to add more than to remove it. Let us know your experience! (and brand)

Comment: @Jolenealaska The brand is Bob's Red Mill. I haven't yet used it on a recipe I normally use cornstarch in. Will try it soon and comment.