# Can I substitute potato starch (katakuriko) for cornstarch in a cookie recipe?

Tags: substitutions, cornstarch

I have a cookie recipe that calls for cornstarch. I was wondering if I could substitute it for potato starch (katakuriko, in Japanese).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corn Starch vs Potato Starch](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37139/corn-starch-vs-potato-starch)

Comment: @Stephie Is it the same for cookies as it is for sauces?

Comment: The recipe would help... If it's a TBSP, it's probably fine to substitute as they generally sub 1 to 1... if it's a cup, then it's probably serving a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

We keep both in the house, and i always seen to find myself in the middle of prep and not being able to find the one I'm looking for. As a consequence, I have subbed katakuriko for corn starch and vice-versa in equal amounts on several occasions, and never had trouble with the results having the wrong texture or tasting strange.

That being said, I have never used a substantial amount (more than a teaspoon or two) in any recipe, either.